# Retrieve data from firebase in sequence

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing FYP in android studio. I'm developing lecture notification app.
I want to retrieve timetable from firebase, in sequence.
For example, lecture time is 9am displays after notification , it should replaced by next lecture timing.

Comment: It looks like this is your first question here at StackOverflow.  Your question is very vague and open.  It needs to be more specific in order for someone to help you.  It sounds like you want someone to create a complete solution for you. To me it sounds like you are a beginner programmer, so you need to first get a pen and paper and break down the logical pieces of your application (parts that will talk to each other) and then the features that you want it to have.  And then objectives to accomplish.  Start will a very very basic application and add each piece one at a time.

Comment: First search the internet and maybe stackoverflow for questions to accomplish each task instead the whole solution.  I haven't had to retrieve records from Firebase, but a quick google search turned up a few libraries that will interface with interacting with the Firebase database in the android framework.  Once you figure that out then you need to show the record in an Android application.  Later you need to figure out how Android notifications work.  That is a whole other beast.  But keep googling and searching stackoverflow because I'm sure that has been solved by other people before!

Comment: Remember: START SMALL!  START SIMPLE!  Do not try to solve the complex problem all at the same time.  Create a "proof of concept" (PoC) and test out your method.  There is no one right way to do things, but experiment and see what works.  Just make one small thing work and then when happy move on to the next thing.  I know you will move slowly, but this is how we all learn eventually.

Comment: Thank you! Yes i am new to android programming. I have been google how to do it but it seems i have unsuccessful during it. Maybe i am not god at searching or explaining my problem. Let me rephrase it, i only need to retrieve data by time ,its a single module, the activity show recent lecture name and time not all of them.